# Why can four-eight "rays" be seen around all stars in astronomy photographs from the Hubble Space telescope?

Tags: star, photography, hubble-telescope

In famous astronomy photographs from the Hubble Space telescope such as [the Pillars of Creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillars_of_Creation), each star has four rectilinear "rays" projecting out in the intercardinal directions, and sometimes four additional rays in the cardinal directions.

[image: Pillars of Creation]

I assume this is some effect of the photography technique of the Hubble telescope - in the images from the James Webb space telescope six rays can instead be seen.

What is causing this effect?